# Get full output of sudo apt-get update

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi

**Is there a way to print out the full output of sudo apt-get update**

I have a script that prints the output of the command in python:

```py
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(["sudo", "apt-get", "update"])
print(output.decode())
```

currently the output I'm getting is:

```
Get:1 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Release
Ign:2 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Release
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Ign:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Get:3 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Packages
Get:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Ign:4 file:/var/cache/openmediavault/archives  Translation-en
Hit:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease
Hit:8 https://openmediavault.github.io/packages usul InRelease
Ign:9 https://dl.bintray.com/openmediavault-plugin-developers/usul buster InRelease
Hit:10 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Hit:11 http://packages.openmediavault.org/public usul InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Get:13 https://dl.bintray.com/openmediavault-plugin-developers/usul buster Release [4363 B]
Fetched 4363 B in 4s (1028 B/s)
Reading package lists...
```

I would like to get this data after it as well:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
64 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: Don't know if raspberry-pi has `script(1)`, but if so, fire up `script`, run the sudo command in there, and after it has finished, hit ^D (Ctrl-D, i.e. End-of-File) and then inspect at leisure the output in the file `typescript` that `script` created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import subprocess

sb = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "apt", "update"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# get the command output
cmd_out = sb.communicate()
# convert from byte string to string
output = cmd_out[0].decode()
print("all output in a variable\n" + str(output))
# number of upgradable packages
upgradable_package_count = str(output[-70:-68])
print("Upgradable: ", upgradable_package_count)
```

end of output:

```
...
Hit:12 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:13 http://packages.openmediavault.org/public usul InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```